# $post->post_meta not pulling any post information in wordpress/php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function in php as shown below:

```
function hello_world( $post ) {
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($post); echo '</pre>'; // Line A
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($post->post_meta); echo '</pre>'; // Line B
    return $post->post_meta;
}
```

I have added `Line A` and `Line B` in the function above for debugging purposes. In the function `hello_world` above, `Line A` returns list of all posts whereeas Line B doesn't return anything.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the wordpress or php code above so that `Line B` returns list of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post_meta doesn’t contain a list of posts, it has extra information that you, a plugin or your theme are adding to a post using `add_post_meta`.

To get the post meta, you use [the `get_post_meta` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

To get all values you can do this:

```
$allpostmeta = get_post_meta ($post->ID);
```

You can also get a specific field like this:

```
$mymetavalue = get_post_meta ($post->ID, ‘your_meta_key’);
```

Comment: like this `function hello_world( $post ) {
   $allpostmeta = get_post_meta ($post->ID);
    return $allpostmeta;
}`

Comment: @user1950349 If you want to return the all post meta for that post, then yes that is what you need to do. If you want to do something else with it first, then you have all the post meta data in `$allpostmeta` to do whatever you need first.

Comment: @FFluffyKitten I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62843815/s-term-is-not-pulling-posts-on-the-basis-of-post-title-in-wordpress-php). Its not similar but its part of the same code. I am wondering if you can have a look.