# 's' => $term, is not pulling posts on the basis of post_title in wordpress/php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php code in which I want to pull posts on the basis of `post_title`. Let us suppose the `$keyword` is `chicago` or `Chicago`.

```
if ($keyword) {
        $query = new \WP_Query([
            's' => $keyword,
            'post_type' => 'abc-xyz',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);
    } else {
        $query = new \WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'abc-xyz',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            //'ep_integrate' => true,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        ]);
    }
    
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($query->posts); echo '</pre>';  // Line A
```

Line A prints the following array when `$keyword` is `Chicago` or `chicago`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 280045
            [post_title] => Chicago
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 680045
            [post_title] => Peoria
        )

    [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 180045
            [post_title] => Peoria
        )

    [3] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 880045
            [post_title] => Chicago
        )

    [4] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 180000
            [post_title] => Chicago
        )
)
```

I am wondering why its pulling posts with the `post_title` `Peoria` when the `$keyword` is `chicago` or `Chicago`.

Comment: Seems that you forgot to tell wordpress you want `Chicago`

Comment: The keyword which I have entered is 'chicago'. Does caps matter ? Even if I enter 'Chicago', its giving me the same results.

Comment: Ni. But I'd say that  your condition smells to me. Have you double checked which query code was really executed?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Ok, I will have a look.

Comment: I am wondering how I can check which query code is executed ?

Comment: Put something like `echo __LINE__; die();`

Comment: Its printing 23.

Comment: Then it means its 23rd line of that script. You can now easily tell which branch it went to

Comment: yes, its 23rd line of the script. Branch it went to? How it would help in solving the problem ?

Comment: OK, you asked me to take a look so here I am (going back to old questions and asking them to take a look at new ones is not something you should really be doing here BTW, but I'll take a look thing time:) ). As @MarcinOrlowski has said, you need to see which part of the `if` statement is getting executed. We don't know which line 23 is so you'll need to tell us! What debugging have you tried? Have you trying doing `var_dump($keyword);` to see if `$keyword` has the correct value? And doing an `echo` in each part of the if/else to see which part is being executed?

Comment: Hi, I have tried the `$keyword` part. I did `var_dump($keyowrd)` and its printing what I am searching for. I haven't tried the `if/else` part. I placed `echo "I am inside the if block";` inside the if block and its showing on 
 the page. Its not going inside the `else block`.

Comment: Do you have the keyword anywhere else in the content of the posts it is returning? `s` searches more than just the post title. The `if` branch is getting executed, so that would suggest you have Chicago" (or whatever the keyword is) somewhere in the main content of those posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FluffyKitten notes, the default Wordpress search is not limited to just the post title. It searches both `post_title` and `post_content`.

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation and I think it searches both `post_title` and `post_content`. I am wondering what code I need to add so that it pull posts based on the `post_title` only.

Comment: In your original question, you were wondering why it was pulling posts that did not have the search term in their title, and we answered that question. In regards to only searching through post titles, there are lots of solutions in the web, you just need to google them.